# American put option pricing by "binomial trees"

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-differential-equations, mathematical-finance

I'm teaching a financial mathematics course and have found a fascinating (to me) numerical phenomenon and wonder if anyone has studied it, or knows anything similar.

I'll try and give a description of what it means followed by a self-contained description of what I'm doing. First of all: an American put option is a product that gives the right to sell a share for a price $K$ (agreed at the outset) at any time up to the expiry time, $t$, of the option. It's assumed that the underlying share is moving according to a geometric Brownian motion (GBM) with known volatility parameter $\sigma$. The interest rate is $r$ and the initial share price is $s$.

The basic idea is to discretize the GBM to a multiplicative random walk on the "binomial tree" with depth $n$. That is: one assumes that at each of the $n$ stages the price multiplies by $u=\exp(\sigma\sqrt{t/n})$ or $d=1/u$. In this derivation, the "risk-neutral measure" is the measure on the multiplicative random walk where up steps occur independently with probability $p=(\exp(rt/n)-d)/(u-d)$ and down steps occur with probability $q=1-p$. One can then define $V_{j,i}$ to be the value of the option if unexercised by time $jt/n$ and the current share price is $su^id^{j-i}$. The approximate arbitrage-free cost of the option is $V_{0,0}$. The scaling of the multipliers guarantees that the multiplicative random walk converges to a geometric Brownian motion in the appropriate sense. It is assumed (and probably proved somewhere) that this converges to the true arbitrage free cost (computed using the GBM rather than the discrete approximation) as $n\to\infty$. I am interested in the dependence of $V_{0,0}$ on $n$, the number of time steps.

Here is the actual calculation that I'm doing: define $V_{n,i}=(K-su^id^{n-i})^+$. One then does a backwards recursion to populate previous levels of the "tree": $V_{j,i}=\max\big(K-su^id^{j-i},e^{-rt/n}(pV_{j+1,i+1}+qV_{j+1,i})\big)$. [The max here corresponds to either exercising the option now or holding it].

Here is a graph of $V_{0,0}$ versus $n$: [image]

It seems that for odd $n$, the function roughly follows one curve, while for even $n$ it roughly follows another. I have no idea why the graph should look like this...

Comment: A rough explanation for the dependence on parity is that if $n$ is odd, the possible share prices at time $t$ are $\lbrace su,sd,su^3,sd^3,\ldots\rbrace$, whereas if $n$ is even the possible prices are $\lbrace s,su^2,sd^2,su^4,sd^4,\ldots\rbrace$.

Comment: Thanks. This gives a good explanation of the appearance of parity. Still no idea why the curves look like bouncing balls - I would have predicted some kind of monotone convergence to the limit... Is there some number theoretic property of the places where the balls "bounce"?  etc...

Comment: Perhaps it's a rounding issue.

Comment: @Anthony: You get kinks in the graph whenever points on the tree cross the strike and/or optimal exercise boundary. The points on the tree for even n will interleave those for odd n of a similar magnitude (as Kevin noted). Hence you get two curves with the kinks for odd and even n roughly halfway between each other.

Comment: @Kevin: The effect seems way too large to be rounding, unless very low precision is used.

Comment: @George - nice. Thanks for pointing that out. This probably will lead to an answer to the question that I originally posed: how fast does this converge to the true option price (I had numerically observed the error seemed to be $O(1/n)$, but I think this more or less explains it: the gap between $su^id^{n-i}$ and $su^{i+1}d^{n-i-1}$ is of $O(1/n)$. 

Comment: My last(?) question on this then: is there any good reason why we should expect the ball bounces to have equal and opposite slopes? Really appreciating the insight here...

Comment: The gap between grid points is $O(1/\sqrt{n})$. This actually gives an error of $O(1/n^2)$ in your equation for a single step (assuming smoothness of the values, and ignoring the fact that you are taking a max). This comes from expanding out as a Taylor series to 4th order in u and d and comparing vs a true normal distribution over the time step. Summing this error over the n steps gives order 1/n. Also, at each point where a max is taken, the values V have a sudden change in gradient, so you have a larger error, but this only occurs at a couple of points on the at each time step.

Comment: You expect the "bounces" to be roughly symmetric as the situation is roughly symmetric as you increase the number of points or decrease it (keeping n roughly within the same magnitude). As the two curves are almost precisely out of phase, they will have a similar gradient where they cross. Btw, finite difference methods (eg, Crank Nicholson) are usually faster to converge, with $O(1/n^2)$ total error for Europeans, but still $O(1/n)$ for Americans, because the max function is not smooth. There are various rather involved tricks to improve on this.

Comment: @George: Thanks very much indeed for the extremely helpful comments. Is there any chance you can package the most relevant ones into an answer so that it can be recorded that the original question is resolved?

Comment: Fully agreeing with Dr. George Lowther I would just like to add that this is a very common issue in binomial/trinomial pricing of options of all types, not just American. It causes serious problems in accurate computation of the price and, even worse, of greeks. And, as was also mentioned correctly, for American options, methods based on finite PDE solving, do not alleviate the problem in full. Analytic approximations can 100-1000 faster and still more accurate than these discrete methods. Please feel free to visit www.oquant.com and try our new analytic approximation. Please pay attention to